# Yahoo search engine not able to index Ajax content?

Tags: seo, ajax, yahoo

Does Yahoo support crawlable Ajax? I'm about solution provided by Google (https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling).

How to make my Ajax content crawlable by Yahoo search engine?

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo does support the AJAX crawling scheme. You can see this by testing the index of an ajax site: In Yahoo, search for **site:ajax.rswebanalytics.com** - this will show the ajax urls.

Answer (score 0):

By default, search engines do not have the capability to crawl JavaScript/Ajax powered content. This includes Yahoo which is powered by Bing. Neither company have announced this capability.